# Looking for Graphite graph templates

Tags: graphite

I've searched the net but cannot find any pretty graphite templates that can be placed in graphtemplates.conf and used in the graph by adding `?template=[name]` to the query string.

I found the solarized-light template which looks as follows:

```
[solarized-light]
background = #fdf6e3
foreground = #657b83
majorLine = #073642
minorLine = #586e75
lineColors = #268bd2,#859900,#dc322f,#d33682,#db4b16,#b58900,#2aa198,#6c71c4
fontName = Sans
fontSize = 10
fontBold = False
fontItalic = False
```

[image: Solarized-light]

This one is nice but I want to be able to select more options. Does anyone have or found a good template which I can use?

Comment: Do you want more templates or more things, a template can define?

Comment: Write them. Porting these values from IDE/editor colour schemes to templates looks pretty straightforward. You can do this and then ask them to include it in git docs maybe. :)

Comment: Where do I get these IDE/editor colour schemes? My own sense of aesthetics is not up to par.

Comment: [This](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) will give you a dive-in into the aesthetics. You can start with porting this one onto a Graphite-web template. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find anything either, so I started one: https://github.com/phillbaker/graphite-templates. Currently has solarized-light (from your post) and solarized-dark. I opened an issue to add [monokai](https://github.com/phillbaker/graphite-templates/issues/3) as well.